# Nextjs - Location for Logical JS/TS Files

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Question about SSG:

The pages directory hosts visitable pages and the API for SSR.

I was wondering if Next has a specific directory to store functions that don't clog up the component file.

For example: A function with FETCH that gets data from API, sanitizes it and then passes it for caching on `getStaticProps`

Comment: That's really up to you. Next.js is not opinionated about that.

Comment: @juliomalves They'll still compile if imported, correct?
Sorry, I'm just new to NextJS.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Next.js is only opinionated about the `pages` folder because the built-in routing is based on its structure. Everything else is up to you.

Comment: @juliomalves Thank you! Everywhere is fine except pages, correct? I've previously used a "lib" folder. Gonna try that.